# Adding new parameter to a web API action method without disturbing the existing contract

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an action method already written in my web api 2.0 project. I would like to add a new parameter without disturbing the existing contract. What is the best way to do that? Appreciate any best practice hints on this :)

Here's the code sample of what I intend to do:

Existing code:

```
[Route("{myId}",Name="MyId")]
Public IHttpActionResult Get(String myId)
{
  //Some more code here
}
```

Url: http://localhost:8888/webapi/1111

Expecting to do something like the below:

```
//I want to keep the route name same for backwards compatibility.
[Route("{myId}/{myName}",Name="MyId")]
Public IHttpActionResult Get(String myId,string? myName)
{
  //Some more code here
}
```

Url: http://localhost:8888/webapi/1111/John
The Url mentioned above hits the method rightly, but I never get the second parameter (myName) populated with John.

Thanks everyone for any help towards this.
Sree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have `myName` as `string?` which is not allowed as:

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

A test controller was created to implement you action

```
[RoutePrefix("webapi")]
public class TestsController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{myId}/{myName}", Name = "MyId")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string myId, string myName) {
        //Some code to show the values of the parameters
        return Ok(new { myId = myId, myName = myName });
    }
}
```

When tested with `webapi/1111/John` the following response is returned

```
{"myId":"1111","myName":"John"}
```

which does include the value for `MyName` as `John`

If backwards uri `webapi/1111` is tried, a `NotFound` response is returned as the template does not match the new action.

To fix this you need to make the `myName` parameter optional. To learn more about that check

[Optional URI Parameters and Default Values](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)

The new route will look like

```
//NOTICE THE `?` ON THE {myName} TEMPLATE
[Route("{myId}/{myName?}", Name = "MyId")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string myId, string myName = null) {...}
```

You will notice that `myName` was made optional in the route `{myId}/{myName?}` and in the action parameter `(string myId, string myName = null)`

Now when tested with `webapi/1111` the following response is returned

```
{"myId":"1111","myName":null}
```

Which would match your expected result for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

String is a reference type so you don't need to make it nullable, it already is.  Remove the '?' and remove the Name from the attribute.  What happens then?